# ImageEditor with selecting a portion of the image for adding comments in Plone

Tags: python, plone

I require an  image editor with the feature of a mark setter in Plone 4.1 wherein a part of the image can be selected. A comment can be set w.r.t this selection mark for editing when a 
workflow sets in.

Comment: There is an image editor for plone, Products.ImageEditor but not with the features you are talking about. Perhaps you can contribute to the project what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plone.org/products/collective.imagetags may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanx http://stackoverflow.com/users/308995/jon-stahl, this definitely is very close to what I want to do with Products.ImageEditor